# Extract text between two strings from a file and save the output

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, script

How to extract the text between two strings from a file and save the output to another file, and invoke it in batch, at command line?

To be more specific, let us say that the input file is `SomeFile.txt` and I want to extract everything between the strings `\StartHere` and `\EndHere` and save it to `SomeFile.log`?

For this, I would need a program, let us call it `TextExtract` to be called on the command line with the four `parameters` like this:

```
> TextExtract SomeFile.txt '\StartHere' '\EndHere' SomeFile.log
```

Are there any specific command line programs that can do that in Wondows 10, or some script that can be run at command line (using parameters as above)?

Comment: Are the two strings going to be per line in the file, or could it span where starthere is on another line and endhere is also on another line, or could it be either of the two?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I have each string ocupying one line.

Answer (score 2):

This operation is easy when using PowerShell.

From the post
[PowerShell Extract text between two strings with -Tail and -Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469896/powershell-extract-text-between-two-strings-with-tail-and-wait)
you could use the PowerShell function from the
[answer by Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470334/165358):

```
function Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ([string]$startPattern, [string]$endPattern, [string]$filePath){
    # Get content from the input file
    $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
    # Regular expression (Regex) of the given start and end patterns
    $pattern = '(?is){0}(.*?){1}' -f [regex]::Escape($startPattern), [regex]::Escape($endPattern)
    # Perform the Regex operation and output
    [regex]::Match($fileContent,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
}
```

An example of a call to the function is :

```
$inputFile    = "D:\Test\THE-LOG-FILE.log"
$startPattern = 'START-OF-PATTERN'
$endPattern   = 'END-OF-PATTERN'

Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings -startPattern $startPattern -endPattern $endPattern -filePath $inputFile
```

To store the found text inside a file, add to the call :

```
Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ... | Set-Content -Path 'X:\wherever\theoutput.txt'
```

Comment: I'm new to PowerShell, so I need to ask: where do I write/save the function? Do I save it in a file like Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings.ps? And then call it with arguments at command line?

Comment: Put the function in a `.ps1` file. Many tutorials for example [Powershell Tutorial for Beginners: Learn Powershell Scripting](https://www.guru99.com/powershell-tutorial.html). To run the script from batch, use a command like `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ..."`. For details see [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make this work. I get the error:
``Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings: The term 'Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.``
I saved the function into a PS1 file, then called it in the PS Terminal in the location where I saved it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems I have to do "dot-sourcing the function".

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I succeded to make this work in a PS terminal, but I can't make it work in a CMD terminal by calling `powershell`. How do I dot source the script in this case?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Probably, I will ask a separate question on this topic of calling the function at command line (I'm not very familiar with Powershell, I looked over the documentation for some time and tried some combination of commands, but it didn't work).

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I think this was my firts attempt. Indeed, if I run the two commands in PowerShell terminal, it generates the correct file.

If I run the two commands toghether (separated by `;` and delimited by `"` and `"`) as parameter of `-Command`, then I get no error but also it generates a file with 2 empty lines!

Comment: @digital-Ink See if using `{ }` encapsulating that way does it without double quotes. Test with and without but I think without. You might also try and test with only and plus single quotes around the command both with and without the curly bracket encapsulation. Process of elimination of all variations but start with only the curly brackets using the semicolon to separate commands. Also look over cmd `powershell /?` as it may give examples and explain better too.

Answer (score 1):

> *...let us call it `TextExtract` to be called on the command*
> *line with the four parameters like this:*
>
> ```all-bat
> > TextExtract.Script .\SomeFile.txt '\StartHere' '\EndHere' .\SomeFile.log
> ```
>
> This changes in syntax when it comes to involving/invoking
> the **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** to interpret your **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** **[script](/questions/tagged/script)**:
>
> ```all-bat
> > PowerShell flag#1 flag#2 ... flag#N & 'Script.ps1' $Args[1] $Args[2] $Args[3] ... $Args[N] [-WindowStyle Hidden] [among other options] ...
>
> > Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "D:\The\Full\Path\To\TextExtract.ps1" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.txt" "StartString"  "EndStrings" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.Log"
> ```

---

[`TextExtract.ps1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742775/why-is-my-locally-created-script-not-allowed-to-run-under-the-remotesigned-execu)

## **Use the \appropriate \scape:**

```bash
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\The\Full\Path\To\TextExtract.ps1" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.txt" "\hic incipit"  "\hic terminus" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.Log"
```

---

> ```all-bat
> $Start = $args[1].replace('\','\\')
> $Ends  = $args[2].replace('\','\\')
>
> $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path | Push-Location
>
> $Path  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($args[0])
> $Logs  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($args[3])
>
> if (!($?)) { 
>     $null | Out-File -FilePath (Resolve-Path $args[3] | Select -ExpandProperty Path ) 
>     $Logs = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($args[3])
>   }
>
> $Expr = "(cat $Path -Raw | sls ('$Start.*$Ends')) -split('($Start.*$Ends)')"
> $Strs = Invoke-Expression -Command "$Expr" ; Out-File $Logs -InputObject $Strs[1] -Force
> ```

---

```all-bat
In sollicitudin tincidunt turpis, amet nec dui feugiat neque 
eleifend id hic incipit Nunc hic terminus quis et tellus 
rutrum placerat. Nam et lorem ligula. Vivamus ante risus, 
volutpat ac ultrices in, ultricies nec dolor. In hac 
habitasse platea dictumst.
```

[image]

---

Set your filter as accurate as possible for the line of interest search.

```all-bat
 sls (('starthere.*endhere'))
 sls (('hic incipit.*hic terminus'))
```

Split the line results and select the appropriate one in line split, where:

```all-bat
...) -split('(hic incipit.*hic terminus)')
[0] before the string of interest
[1] string of interest // ... hic incipit Nunc hic terminus ... 
[2] after the string of interest
```

---

```bash
$Strings=$(gc .\SomeFile.txt -Raw | sls ('hic incipit.*hic terminus')) -split('(hic incipit.*hic terminus)') 
$Strings[1]
```

- Results

```all-bat
hic incipit Nunc hic terminus
```

---

**Obs. 1:** Consider watching for the presence of characters that need to be escaped, as the initial and final search interval here is fictitious, the real one may require some pre-processing `<in code>` editing.

```all-bat
PowerShell   ...   "\hic incipit" "\hic terminus" ...
// <code> $Start = $args[1].replace('\','\\') </code>
// <code> $Ends  = $args[2].replace('\','\\') </code>
```

---

**Obs. 2:** You can invoke this script in drive\folder other than where it is being called:

```all-bat
C:\Windows\System32>PowerShell -executionpolicy bypass -file "D:\The\Full\Path\To\TextExtract.ps1" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.txt" "\hic incipit"  "\hic terminus" "D:\The\Full\Path\To\SomeFile.Log"
```

---

**Obs. 3:** If your command will be invoked in the folder where you have saved the script, you can use path `.\`Relative:

```bash
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\"TextExtract.ps1" .\"SomeFile.txt" "\hic incipit"  "\hic terminus" .\"SomeFile.Log"
```

---

**Obs. 4:** The current version will create the file `"SomeFile.Log"` (`$args[3]`) if it doesn't exist, and if it does, it will overwrite it, and if it's going to create it if it doesn't exist and feed it by appending it, replace:

```all-bat
Out-File $Logs -InputObject $Strs[1] -Force
Out-File $Logs -InputObject $Strs[1] -Append
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Select-String || Sls`](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html)
- [`Remove-Variable|| Rv`](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-variable.html)
- [`Get-Content || Cat || Gc`](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-variable.html)
- [`-Split() || .Split() || Split('("simplistic regex")')`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [`-ErrorAction Ignore || -EA Ig`](https://ss64.com/ps/common.html)  and [`Common Parameters`](https://ss64.com/ps/common.html)